# How to use uniform_int_distribution as the class field in constructor

Tags: c++, class

How to use uniform_int_distribution as the class field in constructor. I am new in ++. I am trying next approach and just got error.

```
class RandomConnectionsProvider : RandomProviderBase
{
public:
    RandomConnectionsProvider(mainDataType operatorsCount);
    ~RandomConnectionsProvider(void);
    static mainDataType GetNextConnectedOper();
private:
    uniform_int_distribution<int>* connections_dist;
    static random_device rd;
    static mt19937 rnb;
};

RandomConnectionsProvider::RandomConnectionsProvider(mainDataType operatorsCount)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> op_dist(1, OperatorsCount);
    connections_dist = &op_dist;
}

mainDataType  RandomConnectionsProvider::GetNextConnectedOper()
{
    return *connections_dist(rnb);//Triing  to dereference as i remember it but got error there
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make `connections_dist` point to a local variable in the constructor. This local variable will be destroyed when the constructor returns, and so the pointer will no longer point to a valid object.

Instead I suggest you skip the use of pointers, and do something like this instead:

```
class RandomConnectionsProvider : RandomProviderBase
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> connections_dist;  // Note: no pointer

    // ...

public:
    RandomConnectionsProvider::RandomConnectionsProvider(mainDataType operatorsCount)
        : connections_dist(1, operatorsCount)
    { }

    // ...
};
```

The part after the colon in the constructor is called an *initializer list* and is used to initialize member variables in the object.

Not using a pointer will help you fix the other error as well, as you won't be needing to use dereferencing. That error, by the way,  is because the function call has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator (so the compiler thinks you are doing `*(connections_dist(rnb))`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the local `op_dist` object is destroyed when your constructor finishes, so you cannot use it afterwards. Your `connections_dist` points to invalid memory.

You have 2 possible solutions:
1. Don't use a pointer, but an object member:
   Use `uniform_int_distribution<int> connections_dist` directly and initialize it using the initializer list, like this:

```
RandomConnectionsProvider::RandomConnectionsProvider(mainDataType operatorsCount)
: connections_dist ( 1, OperatorsCount )
{
}
```

2. Dynamically allocate the object, and by this prolong its lifetime:
You need to delete it again in the destructor, like this:

```
RandomConnectionsProvider::RandomConnectionsProvider(mainDataType operatorsCount)  {
    connections_dist  = new uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, OperatorsCount);
}
RandomConnectionsProvider::~RandomConnectionsProvider() {
    delete connections_dist;
}
```